# How do mRNA vaccines work with respect to presentation of the antigen?

Tags: virology, rna, mrna, vaccine

As I understand it, mRNA vaccines operate by taking a gene for some distinctive feature of the target virus and arranging for the cells of the vaccine recipient to manufacture the proteins that make up the distinctive feature and present them to the body of the host, which will then form an immune response to the feature.

My question is: how is this feature, assuming it has been manufactured, presented to the body? In other words, is the expectation that it would exist as a separate unit and that separate unit would exit the host cell somehow and be recognized?

Comment: Your cited example is the concept behind recombinant viral vaccines, like the ChAdOx1 by Astrazeneca. Nothing to do with mRNA one.

Comment: @Shred I edited the question to remove irrelevant comments about how the genomic material enters the cell.

Comment: I came here by accident looking for an answer on whether the cells contracting the mRNA get destroyed by the immune system. For instance, Dr. Mobeen Syed suggests that the material exits the cell only as: (1) exposed via MHC I, e.g. in case of a muscle cell, or (2) exposed via MHC II in case of antigen-presenting cell, or (3) debris when the cell self-destruction is triggered by a CD8 T cell. Such interpretation seems to be in conflict with the answers here suggesting that the spike material can exit an intact cell by itself. Video: https://youtu.be/9EfToFXwx98

Comment: @RomanRiabenko Well, you should read my comments below in the answers. Concerning cell destruction, when a cell undergoes apoptosis there is a protease cascade that destroys all the proteins in the cell before it disintegrates. Also, as I stated in my comments, a disembodied viral protein would not have the same folded shape by itself that it would have on an intact and complete virus, so it would be unlikely that a fragmentary viral protein would have a useful immunological pattern that could be acquired by a B cell.

Comment: @Shred: It's rather unclear, I admit, but I think the OP means SARS-CoV-2 by "vector virus". Still the Q could be edited for more clarity.

Comment: @Fizz No, Shred is right. I simply made the error of assuming that mRNA vaccines used a vector virus, which is not true. I removed that erroneous statement from my question already.

Comment: You still have a mention of "vector virus" in your Q: "2) is it expected that the **vector virus** would grow that feature on its own self and that new vector virions would emerge from the host cell with the distinctive feature sprouting from their outer shell?"

Comment: @Fizz I removed that part of the question.

Comment: @Fizz: I still haven't found out, maybe it goes without saying: a recombined vector virus - Adenovirus - does not only have the gene for the corona spike integrated into its genome (artificial recombination) but "comes as" modified virus, carrying the Corona Spike on its coat, next to its Adenovirus-Antigenes? Recombined Adeno-vector virus "is grown" in vitro? To recap my self-answer: manipulation of genome prevents translation for purpose of virus construction, however, "patentlike", this attenuation does not prevent translation for presentation of MHC by target cells.

Comment: @Imprisoned Rhesus "when a cell undergoes apoptosis there is a protease cascade that destroys all the proteins in the cell before it disintegrates." That does not imply that piecemeal fragments of "epitopes" exist as debris? This interests me as it doesn't seem very clear what B-cells are able to take up. B cells never take up whole virus - do they just "contact" antigen - no, as they coherently present on MHC 2 which means uptake of foreign antigen as such. Not whole virus?

Answer (score 3):

MHC presentation of cleaved spike protein is only part of the picture; afterall, the immunity conferred by vaccines is largely owed to neutralizing antibodies produced by B-cells, which do not recognize MHC-bound peptides but rather intact antigen. While MHC presentation is important for T-cell (and ultimately B-cell) activation, the fact is that the spike protein encoded by these mRNA vaccines is presented on the surface of transfected cells for B-cell recognition.

Here is a great review that not only discusses the mRNA vaccines but, as far as I can tell, all of the other vaccine strategies as well. It should answer your question in more detail than I would presume to.

[Heinz FX, Stiasny K. 2021. Distinguishing features of current COVID-19 vaccines: knowns and unknowns of antigen presentation and modes of action. NPJ Vaccines 6(1):104](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41541-021-00369-6)

> In the course of cellular SARS-CoV-2 infection (Fig. 1a), the S protein is synthesized from one of the viral subgenomic mRNAs and co-translationally transported into the lumen of the endoplasmic reticulum (ER) by the use of a signal sequence at its N-terminus, comprising residues 1 to 13 of its total 1273 amino acids... After completion of translation, the protein remains attached to the ER membrane through a C-terminal membrane anchor... When S is synthesized as an isolated protein (Fig. 1b) (as in mRNA and adenovirus vector vaccines as well as for production of recombinant subunit vaccines), the pathway of biosynthesis is very similar.

[image]

> Fig. 1: **a** Infected cells: Subgenomic mRNAs for viral structural proteins are translated in association with the ER (S, M, and E) or in the cytoplasm (N), and virus assembly takes place in the ERGIC. Virus particles are transported through the TGN and released from the cells probably via lysosomes. During transport, S is cleaved into S1 and S2 by the cellular protease furin in the TGN. Some spike molecules, not assembled into virions, are also transported to the plasma membrane despite the presence of an ER retention signal15. **b** Transfected cells: Biosynthesis of S occurs in the absence of interactions with other viral proteins. Proteolytic cleavage into S1 and S2 occurs in the TGN similar to that in infected cells, but some shedding of cleaved S1 and conversion of S2 into its post-fusion structure (S2*) may occur in the absence of stabilizing mutations. ER—endoplasmic reticulum; ERGIC—endoplasmic reticulum Golgi intermediate compartment; TGN—Trans Golgi Network; RNP—Ribonucleoprotein; Viral proteins: S—spike, M—membrane; E—envelope; N—nucleoprotein.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the paper. The diagram you embed shows S1, a viral peptide pool, mounted on the exterior of plasma membrane. This can only be possible via presentation by MHC by my understanding. Also, the spike protein has something like 316 different peptides. I would expect these subunits to be presented, not the entire peptide pool all at once.  When a proteasome cleaves a protein I don't think it is predictable what subset of peptide sequences are created. If you are suggesting that the entire protein or one of the pools gets excreted directly by the TGN (continued)

Comment: I think that would be an unproven assertion, because I believe there are range of conditions a protein has to fulfill before it can be transported this way and viral proteins would not, I expect, fulfill these conditions. Furthermore, even a viral protein was execreted directly, it would not have immunological benefit because T-cells can only analyze peptides mounted on MHC, not free-floating molecules. B cells on the other hand bind to structures on complete and folded pathogens. (continued)

Comment: It would seem to be unlikely that a disembodied S protein would fold properly without the presence of the rest of the virion, and if the protein is not properly folded, that would seem to make it unlikely that a BCR would bind to it successfully.

Comment: S1 is not a "viral peptide pool", it is a domain of the spike protein. You can see the structure of the complete spike protein, including S1 and membrane-bound S2 domains in Fig 2 of the review. It is this complete, folded protein (or at least the S2 domain) that is displayed on the cell surface.

Comment: In concert with the cellular machinery, [the spike protein has evolved to fold and enter the secretory pathway of infected cells naturally](https://internal-journal.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fimmu.2020.576622/full). It is not unreasonable to expect that it would follow the same pathway regardless of the absence of other viral proteins. [Here is a paper which detects intact spike protein on the surface of HEK293T cells after transfection with either the wild-type spike protein mRNA or the mRNA of the Moderna vaccine](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2622-0).

Comment: That said, nobody is claiming that it's a perfect process and that the spike protein presented by transfected cells is identical to that on the virus. There are issues with spike protein produced from the vaccines adopting the unwanted postfusion conformation. This has been addressed by a double mutation in the vaccines to destabilize this conformation. [It has also been observed that the vaccine and virus spike proteins show different glycosylation patterns](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acscentsci.1c00058) which may affect immunogenicity.

Comment: @canadiener A "domain" of a viral gene is the same thing as a peptide pool. For example, see this paper where S1 and S2 are referred to as peptide pools: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-92521-4

Comment: @canadiener Molecules are not displayed by themselves on a "cell surface". That is an old pre-2000 idea and is a mistake. Material can only be displayed outside of the cell by specific molecules designed to do that, called "Major Histocompatibility Complexes". Both B memory cells and T cells only bind to peptides, not large folded proteins. MHCs display peptides, not large folded proteins.

Comment: SARS-CoV-2 enters the cell by its spike binding to [Angiotensin-converting enzyme 2 (ACE2 receptor)](https://uthealtheasttexas.com/virtualcare/articles/covid-19-and-heart-disease) on the surface of the cell, e.g. in lungs or blood vessels. Instead, to egress, it [disrupts function and "hijacks" lysosomes](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/nih-research-matters/coronaviruses-hijack-lysosomes-exit-cells) of the host cell. The quote in the answer assumes that the folded spike protein may exit the same way. This makes this path specific to SARS-CoV-2 vaccine, may be not all mRNA vaccines.

Comment: @RomanRiabenko That’s a good point, thanks.  I might try and add it to the answer later.

Comment: Heinz...  "It is believed (...)that muscle cells, fibroblasts, endothelial cells, and/or immune cells such as dendritic cells contribute to the expression of S after intramuscular vaccination..." What does "contribute" mean? My guess: there is no need of non-dendritic cells presenting antigen on MHC for immunizaton to occur. What is contributed to by muscle cells?

Comment: Heinz et al. (linked to) " ... requires the interaction of B cells with the native protein, most likely by recognition of the spike anchored in the plasma membrane of S-expressing cells ..." Did this quote initiate the question answered? What exactly are "S-expressing cells?" If so wished I'll be able to refer to paper(s) that show that B cells are presented antigen on MHC by APC cells (dendritic cells) in lymph nodes - very exciting: there, it's not presenting only (as with Tc's) but it is a "handing over" of presented antigen for uptake  by B cells! 
So, no need to "shed" (misfolding) prot.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong. A mRNA vaccine only contains a mRNA for the protein against which you want to vaccinate, encapsulated in a lipid membrane. These membrane vesicle  fuses with the membrane of the target cell and releases the mRNA into the cell. There free ribosomes can bind to the mRNA and translate it into a protein. Part of this protein is presented on the cell surface by the [MHC complex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_histocompatibility_complex) and thus presented to the immune system. The mRNA is degraded after some time (although it has been modified to slow down this process), no further copies are made or integrated into the genome.

Speaking of virus based vaccines (like Sputnik V or Astra Zeneca) rely on a virus to deliver a piece of DNA into the cell which contains the information on the protein against which you want to vaccinate. This is transcribed into mRNA and eventually translated into protein. From the virus DNA usually the genes which are responsible for replication are removed so you get no new generation of viruses. Also the virus cannot do anything on its own, since it is not alive and needs a target cell and its machinery.

This [resource](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/coronavirus/in-depth/different-types-of-covid-19-vaccines/art-20506465) gives a nice overview over the different vaccine types.

Comment: First of all, this does not answer the question. Secondly, your understanding is incorrect, if you actually read the link you put in your non-answer, you will see that in the section on mRNA vaccines, it explicitly shows a vector virus being used to insert the mRNA into the cell in steps 2 and 3.

Comment: @ImprisonedRhesus Chris's answer is correct. You are reading the wrong section of the link, the part about viral vector vaccines rather than the mRNA vaccine (the top row in the image is the mRNA vaccine; no viral vector there). The part of this answer that specifically addresses your title question is "Part of this protein is presented on the cell surface by the MHC complex and thus presented to the immune system" while the rest addresses other misconceptions in the question.

Comment: @BryanKrause Huh, ok, so I stand corrected, but it is more or less irrelevant to the question how mRNA gets into the cell. I am asking about the presentation afterwards, so focusing on a minor and irrelevant part of my question that happens to be wrong seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ImprisonedRhesus The vast majority of the text in your question is centered around misconceptions of how things work and imagined solutions based on those misconceptions. I think an answer that failed to address those would be incomplete.

Comment: @BryanKrause The question is about how the antigenic material is presented. How the antigenic material gets into the cell is irrelevant to the question. In any case I have eventually figured out the answer to the question (with no help from this community), so I will post an answer.

Comment: @ImThen you should clarify the question.

Comment: @Chris I edited the question to remove irrelevant comments about how the genomic material enters the cell. You know this community would be a lot more useful if it spent more time answering questions and less time obsessing about minor errors in the question. The people who ask questions are typically those who don't understand the subject very well to begin with. If I was a PhD in immunology I would never have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @ImprisonedRhesus You are still mixing vaccine types. A mRNA virus does neither contain virions nor does is replicate. It is simply translated.

Comment: I'd like to kno, about  manufactured adenovirus carrying the corona-spike on its coat? Aas a vaccine producer, how do I replicate the vaccine virus after recombining its (in case of Adenovirus) DNA? I have heard of some kind of helper cells to replikate attenuated "dead" virus in vitra, manufacturing vector virus. Does this technique lead to recombined adenovirus carrying the spike or not?

Comment: @PeterBernhard Please make this into a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> How do mRNA vaccines work with respect to presentation of the antigen?

According to a DynaMed article, the egress mechanisms expected to play a role [are 3](https://www.ebsco.com/blogs/health-notes/mrna-vaccines-covid-19-how-do-they-work):

[image]

(Note that this image may be somewhat misleading, in that [skeletal] muscle fibers [which are very long lived, multi-nucleated cells] don't normally express MHC-I according to [a (peer-reviewed) article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23850081/). I'm unsure if satellite stem cells in the muscle, which serve to [repair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myosatellite_cell) the multi-nucleated fiber cells by supplying nuclei, have MHC-I.)

As you self-answered, in muscle cells, the MHC-I pathway exposes peptide fragments to "killer T-cells" (CD8)... but there's also release of proteins into extra-cellular space from where they are picked up by B cells, which produce antibodies.

Further MHC-II is engaged in APCs present in muscle and lymph nodes; we know at least from the reported side effects of mRNA vaccines that lymphadenopathy (swelling of lymph nodes) does happen [often enough](https://www.mdpi.com/2079-7737/10/7/652/pdf) following mRNA vaccine administration.

I think however that the relative ratios of spike protein (following mRNA vaccine administration) reaching these 3 routes haven't been
exactly quantified. (I've search a fair bit, but I could not find any papers on exactly that issue.)

Ultimately, both memory B cells and memory T cells (hopefully) give long-term immune memory against that kind of infection, which at least give the host a head-start in a race against a new infection.

It's [worth noting](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867421007066) that mRNA vaccines don't produce the same ratios of neutralizing to binding antibodies (to the spike) as a real SARS-CoV-2 infection.

> vaccinees generate more non-neutralizing antibodies than COVID-19 survivors resulting in a lower ratio of neutralizing to binding antibodies. These data were already apparent in the early phase clinical trials but remained unrecognized at the time (Walter, 2020).
>
> [...] the burning question of whether the abundant non-neutralizing antibodies do have a protective effect in vivo will need to be elucidated by follow-up studies

mRNA vaccines also produce a lot more (spike) neutralizing antibodies than a real infection (same paper), at least initially--there's apparently [a fair bit](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.03.02.21252362v1.full) of decay over time though. Both of these suggest that spikes produced by mRNA vaccines get a lot of B cell attention, which might indicate a lot of them spikes produced by mRNA vaccines egress into extra-cellular space.

Comment: As I commented to a different answer, I don't really believe the "extra cellular protein" stuff, unless you give me much more specific info. First of all, B cells only recognize FOLDED and intact pathogens, like a complete virus. The idea that a B cell would successfully memoize a disembodied protein fragment seems unlikely to me. Also, the shape of this fragment would be different than what it would be on a complete virus, so even if it did so, there would be no immunological benefit. (continued)

Comment: Secondly, you have not shown how a disembodied viral protein can exit a human cell. Viruses use a complex envelopment mechanism to get out of cells which is only available to a complete virus, not viral fragments. Genuine cell self-product proteins only can leave the cell through the Golgi apparatus which requires specialized carriers that human-generated proteins are designed attach to. There is no evidence I know of that a viral fragment would be able to adopt these carriers and use the Golgi apparatus to escape the cell.

Comment: "The idea that a B cell would successfully memoize a disembodied protein fragment seems unlikely to me." Please ask that separately as it's a simpler issue to answer on that level, not related to mRNA vaccines. You could even ask it on Skeptics SE. The 2nd issue (protein egress) is more interesting/challenging to prove directly, I admit, but again it's better suited for a separate question. You've basically used this Q of yours to ask two different ones, related to your disbeliefs. (Your counter-theory that only MHC-I works still doesn't explain anti-bodies, I'll note, though.)

Comment: "*B cells only recognize FOLDED and intact pathogens*" That is completely untrue. B cells will recognize foreign sequences or structures however they're presented to them, whether it's a protein fragment or an intact virion.

Comment: S.Seneff, G.Nigh suggested that muscle cell also presents MHC II. "Muscle cells do express MHC class II proteins (Cifuentes-Diaz et al., 1992). As contrasted with class I, class II MHC proteins specialize in transporting intact proteins to the surface as opposed to small peptide sequences derived from the partial breakdown of the proteins (Jiang et al., 2013)." https://dpbh.nv.gov/uploadedFiles/dpbhnvgov/content/Boards/BOH/Meetings/2021/SENEFF~1.PDF

Comment: @Fizz First view first  "figure" up above: seems like there are muscle cells expressing at least some - i.e. not zero - MHCI. As I read from you, just yesterday, muscle cells "overexpressing" MHC are subjet to myositis. Muscle cells do express MHC, correct? Compare picture above.

Comment: @PeterBernhard: Apparently that page with the pretty image is somewhat less reliable than I thought. The article is signed off by two MDs, but they work for DynaMed. I'm not sure why I wrote it was the Canadian Medical Association. I probably had a different page opened as well and confused the two. Looking at their bios, one of the authors [Iacoviello] looks like a fairly reputable academic in infectious diseases, but maybe that immunology detailed slipped them. Or it might be controversial whether muscle cells have MHC-I, but I've not seen the claim of MHC-I outside that image, TBH.

Comment: @PeterBernhard: On the other hand, there's a peer-reviewed [article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23850081/) that says the opposite, so that seems more plausible to me. I would not be surprised if other cells in the muscle like stem cells (which [produce](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3130421/) nuclei that serve as replacements for those in muscle fibers) have MHC-I, but I'd have to check that.

Comment: @Fizz (removed to chat all right by me). The "article" you cite, I read, that's the one. Again, how did you google it? This is awesome as it beats basic textbook wisdom. Even found articles like "MHC2 - two - they shouldn't do! - on myocytes. Just one simple logic: it's undebated that muscle fibers are able to express MHC1 (they go the genes), so in case of infection (re question I found your statement, different question..) the very infection may induce expression. Anyway, why are muscle cells not autoimmunically killed for "misssing self"?

Comment: @Fizz How about setting up question(s) on non-APC cells expressing MHC1- and -2. Could you cite any basic textbook for MHC2 on non-APCs and - inversely - for non-APCs, nucleated -"aha", cells Not expressing MHC1. Aha: you did mention "nuclear production", ... "Do muscle cells "denucleate"...? Thanks for answering at all, even having received your message I haven't managed to scroll down and read your text. I was stunned by the picture. I will soon delete this comment as chat, except for not on "nuclei". My note on simpleminded infection inducing expression might be left undeleted.

Answer (score -3):

The way the antigenic material is presented is via a peptide MHC complex which appear on the surface of the cell. The various proteins present in a given cytoplasm are randomly selected and automatically chopped up by proteosomes and the resulting short peptide chains are then channeled through a special kind of cellular structure called a [major histocompatibility complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_histocompatibility_complex) and mounted on its surface exterior to the cell. If the target antigen protein is indeed being successfully manufactured inside the cell, then we can it expect that these products will be periodically cut up in the manner described and be exposed. The exposed peptide then serves as an example both for helper T-cells to stimulate immune response (such as antibody class switching), and also serves as the epitope to cytotoxic T-cells which can kill the infected cell. Below is a diagram illustrating the mechanism:

[image: MHC mechanics illustration]

Comment: Downvotes with no comments.

Comment: This isn't incorrect, but it's incomplete in a major way to the point of being misleading; the vast majority of mRNA vaccine studies measure (neutralizing) antibodies, but how do you get [any] spike antibodies from this "cytotoxic T-cell"?

Comment: @Fizz Helper T-cells (CD4+) can attach to MHC just the same way that cytotoxic T-cells (CD8+) attach. However, CD4+ cells stimulate an immune response that includes antibody signalling. I added a statement to that effect in my answer.

Comment: You're still missing direct B cell activation, which is a major part of the immune reaction. B cell receptors bind directly to antigen and cause B cell activation, which is then *enhanced* by $T_H$ cells, but not *initiated* by them. The MHC-I pathway is only part of the system. You're also completely missing the MHC-II pathway (which CD4s recognize, CD8s only do MHC-I)  and the effect of professional APCs.

Comment: @MattDMo Let me know if this comment of mine got go be removed, as maybe it refers to some other question, which might exist at Stackexchange. 
 Re "B cell receptors bind directly to antigen and cause B cell activation" . That should work without any uptake of antigen? Do B cells uptake whole virus? Or do they uptake "debris", see above, nothing left after "clean apoptosis"? And, what's more, if presentation on MHC2 needs incorporation, may contact and let go suffice in a situation of activation of memory B cells?