# Following mRNA vaccination, do proteins mostly exit "naked" from transfected cells or by some more indirect route (EVs etc.)?

Tags: microbiology, immunology, vaccination, mrna

Related to [someone's elses disbeliefs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/105052/how-do-mrna-vaccines-work-with-respect-to-presentation-of-the-antigen#comment190782_105079) in how proteins produced from a mRNA vaccine end up in B cells; in theory the process could be more complicated than "naked" egress (which arguably does have simplicity in its favor). There's at least [one paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jev2.12112) that discussed spike proteins observed egressing in extracellular vesicles (following mRNA vaccination) but it doesn't really say whether this is the common route. And from the general gist of that paper, EVs seem to interfere with detection, so I'm guessing that's not the usual route. For yet another alternative, I could imagine that transfected cells first get killed by CD8 T cells and it's mostly this debris that gets picked up by B cells.

Interestingly, on the last angle, [one review](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1748013219301483) mentioned that

> Comparative studies performed by
> our research group and others demonstrated that nucleoside-modified mRNA LNPs
> outperformed unmodified mRNA LNPs in translation capacity, but failed to elicit successful
> CTL [cytotoxic T cell] responses due to the drastically reduced production of type I IFNs [[119](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5523404/), [157](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28987878/)].

So it seems that the mRNA vaccines currently in clinical use for infectious diseases like Covid-19 (which do use nucleoside-modified mRNA) are pretty unsuccessful at killing cells, which makes the 3rd pathway I was considering above somewhat unlikely as a major contributor. (The research group which wrote that review seems focused on cancer immunotherapeutics, and the two cited studies definitely are about that. The lack of CTL activation is a big deal for cancer therapy.)

So, what *direct evidence* is there for how proteins most often come out cells following mRNA vaccination, particularly in nucleoside-modified vaccines?

Comment: During (mRNA) vaccination the spikes mostly don't exit the cells, they get anchored onto the surface membrane. It means that -something nobody talks about- they are likely taken by (dendritic) cells after the cell dies, because the cell is detected by the immune system as "infected". Klling (+phatocytize+presenting on MHC-II the non-self parts) the infected cells is something else almost nobody talks about, whereas it is a very important part of the immune system.

Comment: At the 2nd dose things are obvious: the spikes on the surface of the cell are detected by the antibodies produced after the 1st dose which triggers antibody-dependent cell cytotoxicity (NK,..) and phagocytosis (macrophage,dendritic cells,..)

Comment: [This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-25589-1) did a serious study of the trafficking of the spike, adding a "HA-tag" (in S1) to detect the spike with labeled antibodies.

Comment: @reuns: Thanks for the link. Somewhat inconclusive though. Regarding your other comments, I doubt cell death is **the** major pathway because the vaccine is administered IM and muscle cells don't regenerate if they completely die (they have complex repair procedures if they're only damaged), but there have been no reports of people losing deltoid muscle strength following vaccination. If killer T-cells persistently target muscle cells it results in major pathologies like IBM (Inclusion Body Myositis), which is very hard to treat.

Comment: S.Seneff, G.Nigh suggested that B cells are activated in spleen, not in the muscle. "... the migration of immune cells carrying a cargo of mRNA nanoparticles via the lymph system into the spleen. These immune cells would produce spike protein... and the spike protein would induce B cell generation of IgG antibodies... neutrophils in the marginal zone of the spleen... interact with B cells, inducing antibody production (Puga et al., 2011). This is likely crucial for successful vaccination outcome." https://dpbh.nv.gov/uploadedFiles/dpbhnvgov/content/Boards/BOH/Meetings/2021/SENEFF~1.PDF

Comment: I linked to this [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2622-0) in a comment on the other question. They detect spike protein on the cell surface using labelled ACE2 or an anti-spike antibody.  They don’t talk about it at all in the paper; just the method and results in supplementary information.

Comment: " are pretty unsuccessful at killing cells" - are those vaccines successful  at inducing  B cell production?

Comment: @Fizz "but failed to elicit successful CTL [...] responses due to the drastically reduced production of type I IFNs" - This is of high interest. Thanks. I miss some follow up text explaining your  inference that comes next: ("So it seems...): What is the effect of Inteferon block on dendritic and regular host cells? If there is no interferon dendritic cells do not survive their uptake of virus (interesting!!), and, inversely, presenting regular host cells (muscle etc.)  are not apoptotically killed by T cells (not induced) but collapse to "debris"? B cells not induces in lack of T4 induction?

Comment: @Roman Riabenko Please set up an anwer based on that reference and the like.

Comment: @reuns "... something nobody talks about- they are likely taken by (dendritic) cells after the cell dies, because the cell is detected by the immune system as "infected"... That idiom "Nobody talks about" should wake up the dogs... If anything isn't explicitely mentioned in textbook it should be evident. I do not believe what you say is the following: if infection of target body cell (muscle, epithelium) happens faster than uptake by APC, dendritic cells - "sth. no one thinks of as a possibility" - there should be no apoptotic killing, and that should give a mess - for uptake by PAMP etc./APCs

Comment: @reun Your "first comment" seems more and more valuable.  Please set up a question  if it's right or wrong what you are "trying to say". You mention MHC1 and 2 - if dendritic or macrophages clean up debris by non-apoptotically passed away cells  that would be no uptake of "live virus". Similar to  m-RNA-nano-vaccines  debris may contain  some intact mRNA that is still "workable, presentabl" on MHC1. Even more surprising: Not necessary! Regular dendritic MHC1 uptake just has  to catch up, interconnection to B by T4-Helpers. Then, there is both MHC1 and 2 presentation. Textbook doesn't say so!

Comment: @PeterBernhard Thank you for challenging me to post an answer. I found the article that I referenced relevant, but I do not know the answer. I just tried to make a hopefully useful comment.

Comment: re "picking up debris", Buchrieser et al. e.g., Syncytia formation by SARS-CoV-2-infected cells might be of interest. CoV-infected host cells seem to express spike protein outside the MHC, thus not attracting t-cytotoxic cells -  maybe just falling apart to "debris".